# How to pass dynamic id text box value to another page without refreshing with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('.btncomment').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('SaveTopicInformation.php', {
        tid: commentform.(topic_ + id).value,
        topicdetail: commentform.(topicdetail_ + id).value,
        userid: commentform.(user_ + id).value
    });
});
```

---

I have to pass the 3 text box value to another page. First of all, I display the all the record from database. then, I have comment link for each row. I like to give comment and save the comment for eache record. I use by jquery and php. please help me out. I can't finger out how to pass dynamic text box's value by bynamic name.

Comment: Please use the code button (Looks like: `{}`) to mark your code ;-)

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ is your friend when pasting code. Or even better: properly indent your code while writing it...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access object fields like that. You need to use the array subscript syntax:

```
$.post('SaveTopicInformation.php', {
    tid: commentform['topic_' + id].value,
    topicdetail: commentform['topicdetail_' + id].value,
    userid: commentform['user_' + id].value
});
```

Actually, since you are using jQuery, using `.val()` on a jQuery object wrapping the form element would be much nicer.

Comment: I do like this. It doesn't work out. <form name="commentform"> <input type="hidden" id="topicid" name="topic_<?php echo $topicid; ?>" value="<?php echo $topicid; ?>"/><input type="hidden" id="userid" name="user_<?php echo $topicid; ?>"  value="<?php echo $userid; ?>"/>
   <textarea id="topicdetailid" name="topicdetail_<?php echo $topicid; ?>" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />        
    <a href="#" class="commentlink cancellink" rel="<?php echo $topicid; ?>">Cancel</a>       
      <input type="button" class="btncomment" id="<?php echo $topicid; ?>"  value="Comment" />     
  </form>

Comment: Thanks Master , I write inside the form tag like you said. right?

Comment: before that I write  $.post('searchdata.php',{ variablename: formname.textboxname.value }. it is ok for only one box. but this time, one record has one box and pass the value.

Comment: thanks Master, I use .val() in jquery. I could save in table.
 $('.btncomment').click(function() { var id = $(this).attr('id'); var t1= $('#topic_'+id).val(); var u1=$('#user_'+id).val(); var td1=$('#topicdetail_'+id).val(); //alert(t1+"="+u1+"="+td1); $.post("SaveTopicInformation.php", { tid: t1, userid:u1, topicdetail:td1 });

Comment: if anyone wants to get it, please let me know. I could send by email. Thanks everyone. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample. What it does is listen for your submit button to be pressed, then it grabs **all** of the content from a certain form, and submits it to a server:

```
//Listen for the submit button to be clicked
$('.btncomment').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    'url' : 'SaveTopicInformation.php', //Processor URL
    'type' : 'POST',                    //Send as POST-data
    'data' : $('.myForm').serialize();  //Send the entire form
    'success' : function(data) {        //What to do when the form is submitted
      if (data == 'success') {
        alert('Form submitted!');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps,
spryno724